# All possible 10-digit combinations of digits 0-9 without repeats

Tags: python-3.3

I'm trying to generate all the possible 10-digit combinations of the digits 0-9 without repeats for a math problem, but I can't seem to get my head around it.
I've tried itertools.combinations, but that gets subsequences.
I've also tried random.shuffle, but that's horribly inefficient with multiple repeats.
Is there an algorithm to solve this?

Comment: This is also known as finding the [*permutations*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of the set `{ 0 .. 9 }`.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, thanks to user2864740, I found itertools.permutations. This does what I asked.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like

```
itertools.permutations(range(10), 10)
```

would give you all 10-digit combinations of the digits 0 - 9.